# pseudo-random number generator based on FIPS 186-2

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, encryption

Hi guys I need to generate a random number (160 bytes) based on FIPS 186-2 in .net based on a given key ( Discussion can be found on RFC 4186 eap-sim implementation). What I know is that FIPS 186-2 is implemented as DSA on .net that will give a 40 byte signature bytes not 160. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 160 bytes or 160 bits? Better check.

Comment: Let me check the process on RFC 4186 on how the documentation comes up with the 1280 bit hash value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the algorithm in appendix B of RFC 4186 (alternatively appendix 3 of FIPS 186-2). There is no implementation of it in the .NET framework. Since the algorithm in this case is used for key derivation, you cannot replace it with another random number generator.

In the process, you will also need to reimplement most of SHA-1, since the G-function needed is the compression function of SHA-1, which is not accessible from the public interface to the .NET framework.

Good luck :-)

Comment: Yap that is what I'm looking for and I don't have any cryptology background to start with.

Comment: The biggest part of the work will be the SHA-1 compression function. A good starting point for that would be this: http://www.bouncycastle.org/viewcvs/viewcvs.cgi/csharp/crypto/src/crypto/digests/Sha1Digest.cs?view=markup

Comment: I've beed reading alot about this compression now I'm looking for that part before sha1 add some padding, based on my understanding I shoud not put padding to arrive with the same hash discussed above.

Answer (score 1):

Not my area, but I think FIPS 186 uses 160 **bit** key and salt (or seed).  That's only 20 bytes.

In any case, the `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator` will happily fill a byte array of any length for you. And it's considered safe for Cryptographic work.

Answer (score 0):

i modify the code found at [SHA1 Source code](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/ff697dcf-4334-4000-b6e6-848f2f85f836)

The trick is to pad the message with (512 - message.length in bits) 0 instead of the padding defined in [SECURE HASH STANDARD](http://www.itl.nist.gov/fipspubs/fip180-1.htm)

if the message to hash is in hexa string use:

```
message = message.PadRight((512/4),'0');
```

for Modulo and exponential operation i used Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger